# Create php function to use inside while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How can I create a function to use inside a while loop. Like `the_title()` or `the_meta()` in WordPress?
A simple sample is enough.

Comment: @andho I think he knows, how to "create" a PHP function, but not how to use it in the Wordpress loop. Regarding the problem: you should have a look at the functions.php including its docs. You can define functions in it and use them globaly in Wordpress, afaik.

Comment: @Sn0opy I'm trying to create a template based script and I need help for creating some template tags for my script. like WordPress:
`while (have_posts()) : the_post();`
`the_title()` inside this loop...

Comment: @WHiSPER just create your own function in the functions.php in your theme folder. The function is accessable everywhere in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use globals. For example, assuming you have a global array, here is something that does that (obviously you need to add more robustness such a error checking. plus how you would use this on wordpress would depend on what you are doing)

```
$post= array( 0=>array('title'=>'the title', 'content'=>'this is the content'),
              1=>array('title'=>'the second title','content'=>'we all love seconds'),
            );
$array_index=0;
the_title();
the_post();
next_post();
the_title();
the_post();

function the_title() {
   global $post, $array_index;
   echo $posts[$array_index]['title'];
}
function the_post() {
   global $post, $array_index;
   echo $posts[$array_index]['title'];
}
function next_post() {
   global $post, $array_index;
   $array_index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So from looking at the `the_title()` and related functions, it looks like you should be able to do as follows (untested, but should work):

```
function whatever_you_want( $post_id = 0 ) {
  $post = get_post($id);
  // Display something with data from $post
}
```

If you don't specify any post_id to the function, `get_post()` will retrieve the current post in the loop for you to use in your function.